# rsyslog -- devices have same hostname and pub ip

Tags: rsyslog

I'm working on a remote logging setup for some cellular devices that are on a carrier's private network.  I have it set up to pass syslogs from the cellular devices to a publicly available server.

My problem is that all the devices share the same hostname and because they are on a private network they all share the same public IP gateway address.  Is there a way using a template that I could separate them by a different attribute?  I'm not aware of any variables that would help, but hoping you genius minds could think of something to differentiate all these devices.

If this POC works I'd expand it to 60,000 cellular units that we own/operate so changing hostnames isn't ideal.

Thanks for any input.